# Laravel Carbon does not consider timezone DST

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

Given my `UsersTableSeeder.php` class, I am seeding my database with fake data, using a loop:

```
$numberOfUsers = 150;

DB::table('users')->delete();

$faker = Faker::create();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfUsers; $i++) {
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'id' => $i,
        'firstName' => $faker->firstName,
        'lastName' => $faker->lastName,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => bcrypt("123"),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays((-5 * $i) - 2)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(-5 * $i)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ]);
}
```

The problem here is that when my datetime values are generated, there is a chance it might fall in a DST zone, like between 2017-03-12 02:00:00 and 2017-03-12 02:59:59 (which does happen) and it gives me the following error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2016-03-13 02:08:11' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

Now I understand that I cannot put such a value in my database, because my database is smart enough to know that this zone in time doesn't exactly exit. But is there any way I can 'make' Carbon smart enough to consider DST ? I do not want to manually check it with something like:

```
if ($my_date > 2017-03-12 02:00:00 && $my_date < 2017-03-12 02:59:59)
```

Comment: Have you tried `Carbon::now('Asia/Tokyo')->addDays((-5 * $i) - 2)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` ?

Comment: why do you need to format the date string, it should work by just passing the carbon object, the time zone that it will be used is the one in the settings.

Answer (score 4):

In Fact Carbon can handle DST zones.

```
$date = '2017-03-26 02:01:01';
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date, 'Europe/Berlin');
dd((string)$date);
```

Results in

```
// an extra hour was added automatically
"2017-03-26 03:01:01"
```

Per default Laravel uses 'UTC' for all date and datetime operations (including Carbon). This value can be set in app/config.php

If you actually want to your datetimes be considered in 'UTC' in database a dirty workaround could be something like that:

EDIT:

```
// calculate current offset to UTC:
$offset = \Carbon\Carbon::now('America/Montreal')->offsetHours;

'created_at' => Carbon::now('America/Montreal')->addHours(-4 + $i)->addDays((-1 * $i) - 2)->tz('UTC')->addHours($offset)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Comment: If it handles DST zones, why does it generate an unexisting time for a DST zone ? I'm UTC-5 (Eastern Canada)

Comment: Because default the default is UTC  and UTC does not know DST.  The generated time is perfectly valid in UTC, but could be a time that is not valid in other Timezones

Comment: Even with your dirty workaround, I get the same error

Comment: die you use your own timezone instead of 'Europe/Berlin' ?

Comment: yes I did, I used  `Carbon::now('America/Montreal')->tz('UTC')->addHours(-4 + $i)->addDays((-1 * $i) - 2)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),,`

Comment: I'm sorry but even `Carbon::now('America/Montreal')->addHours(-1 * $i)->addDays(-1 * $i)->tz('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` gives me the error.

Comment: Sorry, I had a logic error.... You also have to add the offset to UTC. See my edited answer. I have tested it and it works for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still get the error when seeding my database with `'created_at' => Carbon::now('America/Montreal')->addHours($hours * $i)->addDays(($days * $i) - 2)->tz('UTC')->addHours($offset)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),`

Answer (score 2):

You can generate your timestamps with Carbon and provide the timezone. Try just:

```
Carbon::now()->format('c')
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. But then I get an error because `2017-04-14T02:36:34+00:00` is not the format my database is expecting, and it's in UTC instead of my local time.